# accessing a DBadapter globally and Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite ERROR

Tags: android, sql

I have a DB that I use in all my activities. There is only one record in the DB.

In the first activity it is opened or created and then put in my globally used object like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // first get the current data from the DB
        myDBAdapter = new MyDBAdapter(this);
        GlobalVars.myDBAdapter = myDBAdapter; // we store the DBAdapter in our global var

        myDBAdapter.open();

        Cursor cursor = myDBAdapter.fetchMainEntry();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        // if there is no DB yet, lets just create one with default data
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            createData();
            cursor = myDBAdapter.fetchMainEntry();
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
        }
```

Now in another activity I access the already open DB like this...

```
GlobalVars.myDBAdapter.updateMainEntry(1,.....);
```

I do not close the DB when leavin one activity to go to the next. The DB is just accessed (since it has been opened at the very first activity).

Only when leaving the app I clode the DB like this...

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onPause();
        myDBAdapter.close();

    }
```

The background why I am also asking this is I get this error...

> Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@48106730 on
>   mainEntry that has not been deactivated or closed

and it seems that my app crashes on certain devices - but I can't find the reason for it during debugging.

**Is that correct and best practice, or do I have to close the DB when I leave the activity and open it when entering the next activity when switching between activities?**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing (I have it tested in a few apps of mine) is to:

- declare database adapter as an activity's instance variable:

  private DBAdapter mDb;
- create it and open in activity's onCreate():

  mDb = new DBAdapter(this);
   mDb.open();
- close it in activity's onDestroy():

  mDb.close();
  mDb = null;

Works like charm. 
A side note: the Application class onTerminate "will never be called on a production Android device" according to the docs.

Comment: yes, this is what I am doing - but the question is how do other activities access this DB. And why do I get the ERROR: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite - though only sometimes?

Comment: Use in in every activity you need your database in. And dont't do: "super.onPause();"  in your onDestroy, just "super.onDestroy();". It is important to finish each activity properly when it is to be finished.

Comment: EVERY activity must have it's own database connection, and close it when finishing the activity. This is the safest approach.

Comment: About your cursor: declare it as an activity's instance variable, and when closing the activity, do:  if(mCursor !=null)  mCursor.close();

Comment: I access the DB only through my one object myDBAdapter and the DB is never closed until the last activity of the app finishes. Do you really suggest, that I have to close/open the DB while switching between activities? Why would my myDBAdapter not be capable of holding the DB and controlling access without closing/opening ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlite as DB for your application. Then you have to create a common class for your whole application Like " DBAdapter ". Then write codes to manipulate the DB. After that you just have to create DBAdapter's object in your activity. Thus you can access your DB from every activity of your app. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db This link can be useful.

Comment: thanks - this is what I have done with MyDBAdapter. Declared liek this: public class WebiDBAdapter ....

Comment: Sorry , i missed some part of your question. Yes , you have to open & close each cursor object before leaving an activity. Also you have to open & close your database in each activity.

Comment: But as I have written, I can access my DB in every activity without closing/opening. And I always access my DB only through the one object of class MyDBAdapter. The ERROR: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor only occurs sometmes (dont know when) - and the app crashes on some of the devices who bought my app - but I am not sure if it's because of this open/close thing...

Comment: Open & Close database in each activity. Also , close the cursor object you have created after it's use has been done in an activity. Hope that will work for you.